# Does AWS lambda data stored on redis remain after finish lambda function?

Tags: memory, aws-lambda, redis

I want to use AWS lambda function with redis.
But I concern that when lambda function finish then data on redis are gone.

The lambda TTL is 15 minutes.
If I set TTL of data that stored on redis as 20 minutes will the data stay or gone?

Comment: That depends on what redis instance you're talking about and how it's configured. Redis is mostly used as a persistent data storage where you control for how long the data you put there is persisted for, but, without further details your question cannot be answered more thoroughly.

Comment: @nitrin0 I added TTL condition

Comment: How about giving it a try? If you're using a "normal" redis instance and you set a key with some data with TTL = 20 minutes it will stay there for 20 minutes. Redis has nothing to do with lambda unless you're instantiating a redis instance inside a docker container image for lambda or something crazy like that. Again, your question needs more details.

Comment: Redis is Redis and Lambda is Lambda. Where is Redis running? Lambda has nothing to do with it... unless you are running Redis in Lambda which would be extremely weird and stupid.

Comment: since when does Lambda have TTL? You can set a timeout but you cannot set how long the Lambda instance is around

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, Redis is *nominally* outside of the Lambda container. Unless you are doing somethign really crazy like using a custom image with a redis cache inside it for your lambda, then when your lambda container is de-commed your redis cache - not being involved in that decom - will remain the same.